# How do I prove/disprove this formula of infinite sums of derivatives.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I am a first year student who wants to learn more about math, specifically how to think like a mathematicians. For that, I came up with a simple exercise to find functions f(x) that satisfy

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d^i}{dx^i}f(x)$$

or show that the trivial solution f(x) = 0 is the only function that satisfies the infinite sum.

I have no idea or pointers on how to solve this. I don't necessarily want a solution to this, I would love to get some hints because appart from basic induction (which I learned from my first year at college) I can't come up with a tool or method that might help me to solve this puzzle (I tried Taylor expansion but it led to nothing usefull).

I specifically want to grasp how mathematicians approach such questions. Where do I start, what should I apply to solve this sum, what is the standart tool to approach this, etc? Trial and error did work for f(x) = 0, but I wan't to be able to solve such tasks in a more *academic* sense.

Comment: What happens if you differentiate both sides?

Comment: $ae^{x/2}$ for real $a$ looks an "obvious" solution since $1 =\frac12+\frac14 + \frac18+ \cdots$

Comment: @saulspatz I get, that the derivative of f(x) on the left hand side is equal to the same sum, just from i=2 if that is correct. By substituting the first equation into it I get (after isolating the f(x) term) that f(x) = 0. The problem is, that I don't know how to differentiate the right hand side, since the sum goes to infinity. Just starting from i=2 doesn't feel right...

Comment: You are substituting wrong. If you do it right, you don't get $f(x)=0$, you get $f'(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating both sides gives
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y-\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$2\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\frac{2}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
Then integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives
$$2\ln{(y)}=x+c_1$$
$$\ln{(y)}=\frac{1}{2}x+c_2$$
$$y=e^{\frac{1}{2}x+c_2}=c_3 e^{\frac{1}{2} x}$$

Comment: Can we differentiate this infinite sum though?

Comment: Why wouldn't we be able to? The function is obviously infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me now. Marking as solved.

Comment: I believe you need uniform convergence of the series to differentiate term by term.